# How do you configure a Maven/SpringBoot Project's pom.xml for docker?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, docker

I am attempting to dockerize my SpringMVC application via Maven. My intent is to have an image that I can then proceed to expose and display via my web browser.

Unfortunately, [in following this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker), I appear to still lack a critical piece of understanding concerning the pom.xml edits I must make to achieve this, and the Dockerfile.

======

## Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

======

Here is the [source code's pom.xml](https://github.com/dnmorris7/teluskoSpringBoot/blob/module5/pom.xml) in its latest revision.

======

## Here is my latest attempt at revision, in following the [example pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot-docker/blob/master/complete/pom.xml) of the SpringIO guide I referenced above (dependencies section not included).

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.davidonus</groupId>
    <artifactId>davidonusSpringDemo1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <!-- tag::packaging[] -->
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>davidonusSpringDemo1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- tag::docker[] -->
        <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>DavidSpringTime</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <build>


        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- tag::plugin[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::plugin[] -->

            <!-- tag::unpack[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::unpack[] -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

## Here are my present results, using the command `mvn install build:docker`

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.050 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-15T13:24:01-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:unpack (unpack) on project davidonusSpringDemo1: Unable to update Marker timestamp: /home/david/Desktop/DevOps2019/springBoot/teluskoSpringBoot/target/dependency-maven-plugin-markers/com.davidonus-davidonusSpringDemo1-jar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.marker: Unable to update last modified timestamp on marker file /home/david/Desktop/DevOps2019/springBoot/teluskoSpringBoot/target/dependency-maven-plugin-markers/com.davidonus-davidonusSpringDemo1-jar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.marker -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

======

In summary, [given my original pom.xml](https://github.com/dnmorris7/teluskoSpringBoot/blob/module5/pom.xml), **what changes would you implement** to make my SpringBoot + Maven project deployable as a docker image and container?

Furthermore, are there adaptions to my Dockerfile that you'd make? Your consultation is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your springboot code ready with pom.xml. Then follow below steps to containerize your application.

- `git clone https://github.com/dnmorris7/teluskoSpringBoot` (I'm cloning your springboot code)
- `git checkout module5` (checked out module5 branch)
- Created Dockerfile in your git codebase with following contents:

```
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-8-slim AS build
COPY . /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM java:8-alpine
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/*.jar /app.jar
CMD java -jar app.jar
```

**NOTE:** I'm using docker multi-stage build where in first stsage maven builds the jar and in the second stage we copy that jar in java image.

- Now build your docker image `docker build -t appimage:v1 .`
- Run your docker container `docker run -it -d -p 9090:9090 appimage:v1`
- Hit the api to check if its working fine.

```
$ curl localhost:9090/home
{"timestamp":"2019-06-16T05:34:26.655+0000","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"/pages/home.jsp","path":"/home"}
```

Please hit the correct base url, I tried with `/home`

**NOTE:** If you want to provide your own custom `application.properties` then change the `java -jar` command in `Dockerfile` to `CMD java -jar app.jar --spring.config.additional-location=application.properties` and change the docker run command to `docker run -it -d -v application.properties:/application.properties -p 9090:9090 appimage:v1` where `application.properties` is the one which you provide from outside.

Comment: Can you please clarify about "hitting the correct base URL?" Are you saying I must modify my application.properties file? I learned how to reconfigure my maven project to package the application as a .war but I'm still having some issues having Docker and AWS host my site. 

If there is something within the code that's barring me that you've noticed, I appreciate such clarification. All I get is `curl localhost:9090/home
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9090: Connection refused`

Comment: As you see in my answer. I was able to hit `localhost:9090/home` it is also returning me the output but as 404 method not found response. What I said was if you know on what path your application is exposed then use that path. Regarding `application.properties` I just mentioned it so that you know how you can override the variables.

Comment: Please follow my steps as it is. You should be unblocked.

Comment: The thing finally works. I just had to add some tweaks to your code.

First off all, its a war I'm trying to make. Second of all, I needed to expose the ports. So in the end, the Dockerfile became this: `FROM maven:3.6-jdk-8-slim AS build
COPY . /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM java:8-alpine
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/*.war /app.war

EXPOSE 9090
CMD java -jar app.war`

Answer (score 0):

I think not much is missing. Or even better there may be even too many things.

First, you need to tell the docker maven plugin to run. The [maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Packaging) defines which plugins run at what phase. So all other plugins need an execution configuration somewhere (in a parent pom or in yours). Second, there is no need to unpack the created jar file. Spring Boot will create an executable jar file automatically. You only need to tell the docker maven plugin about it (where it is created)

This would be the Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp

ARG JAR_FILE

ADD target/${JAR_FILE} /usr/share/myapp.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/share/myapp.jar"]
```

And this your pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot-docker</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Spring Boot Docker</name>
    <description>Getting started with Spring Boot and Docker</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- tag::plugin[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::plugin[] -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The unpack goal of the dependency plugin can be removed. This way the jar is added into the image and run directly. Hope it works!